# How to get Log of the Day in Android?

Tags: android

I'm writing the code to get the log of all activities which user does in his android device and I succeed. The code is shown below .I had two questions

Que 1 :- How to get the log of whole day?
Que 2 :- How to get and display called numbers, sms numbers mms number etc?

Due to stackoverflow limitation complete output is not shown because it exceed 6000 characters

```
private String getFormattedKernelVersion() 
{
    String procVersionStr;

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/version"), 256);
        try {
            procVersionStr = reader.readLine();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

        final String PROC_VERSION_REGEX =
            "\\w+\\s+" + /* ignore: Linux */
            "\\w+\\s+" + /* ignore: version */
            "([^\\s]+)\\s+" + /* group 1: 2.6.22-omap1 */
            "\\(([^\\s@]+(?:@[^\\s.]+)?)[^)]*\\)\\s+" + /* group 2: (xxxxxx@xxxxx.constant) */
            "\\([^)]+\\)\\s+" + /* ignore: (gcc ..) */
            "([^\\s]+)\\s+" + /* group 3: #26 */
            "(?:PREEMPT\\s+)?" + /* ignore: PREEMPT (optional) */
            "(.+)"; /* group 4: date */

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PROC_VERSION_REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(procVersionStr);

        if (!m.matches()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Regex did not match on /proc/version: " + procVersionStr);
            return "Unavailable";
        } else if (m.groupCount() < 4) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Regex match on /proc/version only returned " + m.groupCount()
                    + " groups");
            return "Unavailable";
        } else {
            return (new StringBuilder(m.group(1)).append("\n").append(
                    m.group(2)).append(" ").append(m.group(3)).append("\n")
                    .append(m.group(4))).toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        Log.e(TAG,
            "IO Exception when getting kernel version for Device Info screen",
            e);

        return "Unavailable";
    }
```

output is:

```
   --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
    01-23 15:59:59.042 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.updatecenter       for service com.sonyericsson.updatecenter/.UpdateCenterService: pid=5181 uid=10013 gids={3003, 2001, 1015}
    01-23 16:00:09.042 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.scoreloop.magicbox for service com.scoreloop.magicbox/.service.MagicBoxService: pid=5189 uid=10023 gids={3003, 1015}
   rvice for service com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/.SecureClockStartupService: pid=5236 uid=10104 gids={3003}
    01-23 16:14:35.709 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=2
    01-23 16:19:33.351 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor (pid 4080): hidden #16
    01-23 16:19:33.351 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.es.BootService in 24960ms
01-23 16:24:06.179 W/ActivityManager(  247): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.updatecenter/.UpdateCenterService in 34957ms
01-23 16:24:06.179 W/ActivityManager(  247): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.scoreloop.magicbox/.service.MagicBoxService in 44951ms
01-23 16:24:11.149 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.android.datamonitor for service com.sonyericsson.android.datamonitor/com.sonyericsson.app.costcontrol.service.DataTrafficService: pid=5392 uid=10058 gids={3003}
01-23 16:27:28.838 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.facebook.katana for service com.facebook.katana/.service.MediaUploadService: pid=5399 uid=10024 gids={3003, 1006, 1015}
01-23 16:29:38.491 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.wsandroid.suite for service com.wsandroid.suite/.core.services.BootService: pid=5425 uid=10126 gids={3003, 1015, 1007}
01-23 16:29:48.491 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.updatecenter for service com.sonyericsson.updatecenter/.UpdateCenterService: pid=5435 uid=10013 gids={3003, 2001, 1015}
01-23 16:34:05.759 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.scoreloop.magicbox for service com.scoreloop.magicbox/.service.MagicBoxService: pid=5445 uid=10023 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 16:45:22.551 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=null interfaceName=null networkType=2
01-23 16:45:22.571 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=1 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=null networkType=2
01-23 16:45:22.941 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.appshare for broadcast com.sonyericsson.appshare/.backend.SyncSchedulerReceiver: pid=5467 uid=10138 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 16:45:23.091 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.google.android.gm for broadcast com.google.android.gm/.downloadprovider.DownloadReceiver: pid=5475 uid=10018 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 16:45:28.901 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=2
01-23 16:53:41.072 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:BackgroundFriendService for service 
01-23 17:04:39.991 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.scoreloop.magicbox for service com.scoreloop.magicbox/.service.MagicBoxService: pid=5611 uid=10023 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 17:04:49.991 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.updatecenter for service com.sonyericsson.updatecenter/.UpdateCenterService: pid=5630 uid=10013 gids={3003, 2001, 1015}
01-23 17:05:28.529 V/BackupManagerService(  247): Backup requested but nothing pending
01-23 17:13:59.866 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=3 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=2GVoiceCallStarted interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=2
01-23 17:13:59.886 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.facebook.orca for broadcast com.facebook.orca/.phone.TelephonyReceiver: pid=5659 uid=10148 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
01-23 17:14:00.036 D/StatusBarService(  313): Notification has fullScreenIntent; sending fullScreenIntent
01-23 17:14:00.036 I/ActivityManager(  247): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10840000 cmp=com.android.phone/.SemcInCallScreen } from pid -1
01-23 17:14:00.746 W/WindowManager(  247): Layout repeat skipped after too many iterations
01-23 17:14:00.746 W/WindowManager(  247): Layout repeat skipped after too many iterations
01-23 17:14:00.746 W/WindowManager(  247): Layout repeat skipped after too many iterations
01-23 17:14:00.756 W/WindowManager(  247): Animation repeat aborted after too many iterations
01-23 17:14:02.796 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.widget.analogclock (pid 4656): hidden #16
01-23 17:14:02.806 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon for broadcast org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon/.PhoneStateReceiver: pid=5675 uid=10152 gids={3003, 1007, 1015}
01-23 xx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.SemcInCallScreen (has extras) } from pid 351
01-23 17:21:03.821 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.idd.agent (pid 4221): hidden #16
01-23 17:21:03.821 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon (pid 5675): hidden #17
01-23 17:21:04.161 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon for broadcast org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon/.PhoneStateReceiver: pid=5778 uid=10152 gids={3003, 1007, 1015}
01-23 17:21:04.352 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=3 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=2GVoiceCallStarted interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=2
01-23 17:21:04.521 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.androidapp.fbmusiclike (pid 4305): hidden #16
01-23 17:21:05.101 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.idd.agent for broadcast com.sonyericsson.idd.agent/.IDDAutoStart: pid=5788 uid=10010 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 17:21:05.521 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.androidapp.fbmusiclike for broadcast com.sonyericsson.androidapp.fbmusiclike/.facebook.AvailabilityChangeReceiver: pid=5797 uid=10011 gids={3003}
01-23 17:21:06.021 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.facebook.proxylogin (pid 4358): hidden #16
01-23 17:21:06.021 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.statusswitch (pid 481): hidden #16
01-23 17:21:06.031 W/ActivityManager(  247): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.statusswitch/.UpdateService in 5000ms
01-23 17:21:id=5930 uid=10018 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 17:27:42.752 W/InputManagerService(  247): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b3b21e0 (uid=10018 pid=5930)
01-23 17:27:46.282 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.wsandroid.suite for service com.wsandroid.suite/.core.services.BootService: pid=5952 uid=10126 gids={3003, 1015, 1007}
01-23 17:27:56.292 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.updatecenter for service com.sonyericsson.updatecenter/.UpdateCenterService: pid=5962 uid=10013 gids={3003, 2001, 1015}
01-23 17:28:06.282 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.scoreloop.magicbox for service com.scoreloop.magicbox/.service.MagicBoxService: pid=5970 uid=10023 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 17:39:36.512 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront for service com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront/.service.StoreFrontService: pid=5991 uid=10042 gids={3003}
01-23 17:45:26.520 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=null interfaceName=null networkType=2
01-23 17:45:26.540 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=1 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=null networkType=2
01-23 17:45:26.730 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.sonyericsson.appshare for broadcast com.sonyericsson.appshare/.backend.SyncSchedulerReceiver: pid=6008 uid=10138 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 17:45:32.520 I/TelephonyRegistry(  247): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=2
01-23 17:47:41.072 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:BackgroundFriendService for service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.googlenav.friend.android.BackgroundFriendService: pid=6044 uid=10050 gids={3003, 1015}
01-23 17:49:22.453 I/ActivityManager(  247): No longer want com.sonyericsson.usbux (pid 315): hiodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b48a9a8
01-23 18:35:18.629 I/ActivityManager(  247): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.providers.talk/messagesByAcctAndContact/1/saklani.sanjeev%40gmail.com flg=0x34000000 cmp=com.google.android.talk/.ChatScreen bnds=[0,94][320,158] (has extras) } from pid -1
01-23 18:35:18.699 I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.google.android.talk for activity com.google.android.talk/.ChatScreen: pid=6413 uid=10121 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
01-23 18:35:28.349 W/InputManagerService(  247): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b50a888 (uid=10121 pid=6413)
01-23 18:35:29.749 I/ActivityManager(  247): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED cat=[dashingsanchit@gmail.com] dat=content://gmail-ls/unread/^i flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivity bnds=[0,94][320,158] (has extras) } from pid -1
01-23 18:35:29.749 W/ActivityManager(  247): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED cat=[dashingsanchit@gmail.com] dat=content://gmail-ls/unread/^i flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivity bnds=[0,94][320,158] (has extras) }
01-23 18:35:40.479 I/Activin permission android.permission.PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT in package com.android.vending
01-23 19:13:48.480 W/PackageManager(  247): Unknown permission android.permission.MANAGE_USERS in package com.android.vending
01-23 19:13:48.480 W/PackageManager(  247): Unknown permission android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS in package com.android.vending
01-23 19:13:48.510 W/PackageManager(  247): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.permission.CUSTOMIZATION in package com.sonyericsson.retaildemo
01-23 19:13:48.510 W/PackageManager(  247): Not granting permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to package com.sonyericsson.retaildemo (protectionLevel=2 flags=0xbe45)
01-23 19:13:48.510 W/PackageManager(  247): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.permission.LIVEVIEW_API in package com.sonyericsson.androidapp.timescapefeedsplugin
01-23 19:13:48.510 W/PackageManager(  247): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.permission.CONTACTS_PICK_CONVERSATIONS_TARGET in package com.sonyericsson.conversations
01-23 19:13:48.510 W/PackageManager(  247): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.permission.ACCESS_PROTECTED_CONTACTS in package com.sonyericsson.conversations
01-23 19:13:48.510 Was) }, flags=2
01-23 19:15:04.730 E/fb_music_like( 6974): No action, ignoring intent
01-23 19:15:04.73T freed 174K, 50% free 2892K/5767K, external 743K/1036K, paused 27ms
01-23 19:15:16.990 D/dalvikvm( 3102): GC_CONCURRENT freed 461K, 46% free 3767K/6855K, external 743K/1036K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-23 19:15:17.180 D/dalvikvm( 5816): GC_CONCURRENT freed 442K, 49% free 3119K/6087K, external 743K/1036K, paused 1ms+3ms
01-23 19:15:17.630 D/dalvikvm( 3278): GC_EXPLICIT freed 200K, 51% free 2875K/5767K, external 743K/1036K, paused 25ms
01-23 
01-23 19:15:22.480 D/dalvikvm(  247): GC_EXPLICIT freed 387K, 38% free 7506K/11975K, external 1343K/1943K, paused 69ms
01-23 19:15:23.390 D/dalvikvm( 6907): GC_CONCURRENT freed 525K, 45% free 3675K/6599K, external 1330K/1607K, paused 3ms+3ms
01-23 19:15:23.580 D/dalvikvm( 6907): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1062K, 55% free 3089K/6855K, external 924K/1436K, paused 54ms
```

Sent from my Sony Ericsson Xperia mini pro

Comment: "I'm writing the code to get the log of all activities which user does in his android device and I succeed" -- fortunately, your technique will not work on Android 4.1 and beyond, as you no longer will have access to log data other than what is logged by your own process.

Comment: "Due to stackoverflow limitation complete output is not shown because it exceed 6000 characters"  Good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 12hours of continuous R & D , I got the solution. This will not only show one day call log but the entire Call log of your cell.

Here is the code

Copy this method in java file and call this method in oncreate()

```
private void getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append( "Call Details :");
    while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
    String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
    String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
    switch( dircode ) {
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
    dir = "OUTGOING";
    break;

    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
    dir = "INCOMING";
    break;

    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
    dir = "MISSED";
    break;
    }
    sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    tvcall.setText(sb);
    }
```

In Xml file paste this code , take a scrollview and a textview like this

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layoutmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Take a Textview & initialize and call the above method in OnCreate() like this

```
TextView tvcall;
tvcall=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.call);
getCallDetails();
```

Output is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```